# sed match pattern and act on x lines after

Tags: sed

I'm trying to find a way to comment out a block (multiple lines) in a configuration file. I'd like to match the first line but also act on each line after that.

```
sed '/\/Some\/Foo\/Bar\/String/' config.file
```

The following example "code" is what I'm trying to match and comment out. The block will always end with a } but I also know the number of lines after the pattern match so this one would be pattern line + 6.

```
foo { '/Some/Foo/Bar/String' :
    key1 => value1,
    key2 => value2,
    key3 => value3,
    key4 => value4,
    key5 => value5,
}
```

Results after sed command

```
#foo { '/Some/Foo/Bar/String' :
#    key1 => value1,
#    key2 => value2,
#    key3 => value3,
#    key4 => value4,
#    key5 => value5,
#}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`sed` allows us to define ranges of lines and then apply substitutions only within those ranges.  We can define a range starting with a line containing `Some/Foo/Bar/String` and ending with a line containing `}` and then apply a substitute command to comment out those lines:

```
$ sed '\|/Some/Foo/Bar/String|,/}/ s/^/#/' file
#foo { '/Some/Foo/Bar/String' :
#    key1 => value1,
#    key2 => value2,
#    key3 => value3,
#    key4 => value4,
#    key5 => value5,
#}
```

#### Details

- `\|/Some/Foo/Bar/String|, /}/`

  This defines the range.  It could have been written as `/\/Some\/Foo\/Bar\/String/, /}/` but, to avoid backslashes, I used `|` as the delimiter in place of `/` for the first regex.
- `s/^/#/`

  This is applied only to lines in the range and it comments them out.

Comment: Thanks that works great I didn't know sed can define a range then process based on just that range.

Comment: Why include the backslash before the first vertical-bar (in `\|`) but not before the second one (in `String|,`)? If this is to escape the vertical-bar, why not just choose a delimiter that doesn't need escaping, like "%" or "@" or "!" ?

Comment: @KevinFegan In the pattern `\|/Some/Foo/Bar/String|`, the delimiter is `|`.   The initial backslash is what tells sed to use `|` as the delimiter instead of the default `/`.  For more info on the use of standard and nonstandard delimiters when selecting ranges of lines, see [Section 4.3 "selecting lines by text matching" of the GNU sed manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Regexp-Addresses)